# Woocommerce wc_get_product() function only partially working for me

Tags: hook-woocommerce

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$product_title = $product->get_name();
$product_price = $product->get_price();
$product_sku = $product->get_sku();
```

$product_title returns the product name, price and sku are blank and I have no idea why. They definitely exist when I check the product which is a simple one

is this valid code? I don't what else to try.